# Bitfinex's Websocket API "hello world" results in ECONNREFUSED error

Tags: node.js, websocket, bitcoin

[Bitfinex's Websocket API](http://docs.bitfinex.com/#public-channels) has the following demo on how to init a connection:

```
//using the ws library
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var w = new WebSocket("wss://api2.bitfinex.com:3000/ws");
w.onmessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.data);
};
```

Running that example with `node.js` version `v5.9.1` and `ws` version `1.0.1` results in the following error:

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 178.249.189.15:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
```

What is the cause of that error?

Answer (score -1):

The server is refusing connection...it might be the port (:3000) or the Host name.
Current host for Version 2 is api.bitfinex.com - full url I use is:
wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws/2 as of (7/11/2017)